# Cauchy Principal Value Integral of $P V \int\limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{x(x^4-1)} dx .$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$ P V \int\limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{x(x^4-1)} dx .$$

I would be very grateful if you could help me solving this integral.
I tried to let $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z^{4}-1)} $ and integrate around a large closed circle in the upper-half complex plane indented at the origin, with 3 poles on the real axis  $ \displaystyle +1,-1,0 $ and a singularity point in $ +i $
My result was :

$$ P V \int\limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{x(x^4-1)} dx  = 0 . $$

Is that correct?

**My attempt:**
$P V \int\limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{x(x^4-1)} dx = \oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z(z^4-1)} dz = 2\pi i Res(f(z),+i) + \pi i Res(f(z),+1) + \pi i Res(f(z),-1) + \pi i Res(f(z),0) = \frac{\pi i}{2} + \frac{\pi i}{4} +\frac{\pi i}{4} - \pi i = 0. $

Comment: TMM has changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure that for your residue, the points on the contour are pi*i*Res and then in the contour the result is 2pi i Res

Comment: Yes,i considered the residue as you suggested.

Comment: I did the integral out myself and got zero as well.

Comment: But the integrand is not even. Is your method still working? I am also new in complex variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I only hope we are not making the same error.. :)

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah I wanted to comment but didn't have the ability to.

Comment: You need to calculate the residue at each specific point that belongs to the region.  Can you show your progress, Matt, so we can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get zero, but here you will see that the only residue computation is at $z=i$.  Indent about each pole on the real axis into a semicircular contour above the real axis.  Each indentation is a semicircle above the real axis of radius $\epsilon$. You then get

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x (x^4-1)} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \frac{e^{\phi}}{(-1+\epsilon e^{i \phi}) (-4 \epsilon e^{i \phi})} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \frac{e^{\phi}}{(\epsilon e^{i \phi})(-1+\epsilon^4 e^{i 4 \phi})} + \\ i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \frac{e^{\phi}}{(1-\epsilon e^{i \phi}) (4 \epsilon e^{i \phi})} = \frac{i 2 \pi}{i (-4 i)}$$

The RHS is $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the pole at $z=i$.  This simplifies to

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x (x^4-1)} - i \frac{\pi}{4} + i \pi - i \frac{\pi}{4} = i \frac{\pi}{2}$$

From this, the PV of the integral may be deduced to be zero.

Comment: Really helpful explanation, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matt: you're welcome.  Please remember to accept a solution if you found it useful by clicking the checkmark to the left.